# awk/grep replace 2nd match after first match in text file while in foreach loop

Tags: foreach, sed, awk, grep

Okay I will try to describe my problem here. I have a file that looks like this:

sta WP00 34.07335 -106.91932 1.43

time 10/23/2013 20:10:17

net XO

datalogger Passcal_q330_linear 0100000EAA23E50F # 2847

sensor trillium_240_2 0 583

```
    axis Z 0 0 - 1 1
    axis N 0 90 - 2 1
    axis E 90 90 - 3 1
    samplerate 40sps
    channel Z BHZ 00
    channel N BHN 00
    channel E BHE 00
    samplerate 1sps
    channel Z LHZ 00
    channel N LHN 00
    channel E LHE 00
```

add

close sensor trillium_240_2 10/23/2013 20:10:17

sensor trillium_120 0 279

```
    axis Z 0 0 - 4 1
    axis N 0 90 - 5 1
    axis E 90 90 - 6 1
    samplerate 40sps
    channel Z BHZ 01
    channel N BHN 01
    channel E BHE 01
    samplerate 1sps
    channel Z LHZ 01
    channel N LHN 01
    channel E LHE 01
```

add

close sensor trillium_120 10/23/2013 20:10:35

#

sta WP00 34.07335 -106.91932 1.43

time 10/28/2013 20:20:28

net XO
datalogger Passcal_q330_linear 0100000EAA23E50F # 2847

sensor trillium_240_2 0 583

```
    axis Z 0 0 - 1 1
    axis N 0 90 - 2 1
    axis E 90 90 - 3 1
    samplerate 40sps
    channel Z BHZ 00
    channel N BHN 00
    channel E BHE 00
    samplerate 1sps
    channel Z LHZ 00
    channel N LHN 00
    channel E LHE 00
```

add

close sensor trillium_240_2 10/28/2013 20:20:28

sensor trillium_120 0 268

```
    axis Z 0 0 - 4 1
    axis N 0 90 - 5 1
    axis E 90 90 - 6 1
    samplerate 40sps
    channel Z BHZ 01
    channel N BHN 01
    channel E BHE 01
    samplerate 1sps
    channel Z LHZ 01
    channel N LHN 01
    channel E LHE 01
```

add

close sensor trillium_120 10/28/2013 20:20:45

Sorry to give you such a long part of the file but I want to make sure you see everything. There are more blocks of meta-data for each station (sta, in this case is WP00). I want to replace the time of the first and second "close" statements,

i.e., close sensor trillium_240_2 10/23/2013 20:10:17 and 
close sensor trillium_120 10/23/2013 20:10:35
with the third close statement date and time. So I want them to read close sensor trillium_240_2 10/28/2013 20:28:28 and close sensor trillium_120 10/28/2013 20:28:28, and so on and so forth for each block of station entries.

To put it a different way I want to use the 2nd matched close statement time and date to replace the first two before it. Or you could think of it as the 3rd matched close statement time and date replacing the first two matched time and dates that precede it.

Additionally to make this harder, if it's the last station entry I want to make the close time and date be 12/31/2500 23:59:59.

I have this text file that I am looping over by station, so I would like to be able to do this automatically for any nth amount of entries. I've tried using grep, awk, and sed in various way to get this logic to work but can't seem to figure it out. Any help or push in the right direction would be great. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

this command should do what you want:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{
        if(/^close/){i++
            if(i<3)a[NR]=$1FS$2FS$3
            if(i==3)
                for(x in a)
                    a[x]=a[x]FS$4FS$5
            l=NR
        }
        next
    } 
    FNR in a{$0=a[FNR]}
    FNR==l{$0=$1FS$2FS$3FS"12/31/2500 23:59:59"}7' file file
```

Comment: Kent, thanks! Looking at the syntax this is in bash. I'm less familiar with bash and more with csh and tsch so I have some questions..that seemed to work for the first station. If I were looping through each of the stations, say stalist="WP00 WP01 WP02 WP03 WP04" would that be x or a? I tried it both ways and it didn't seem to work. How would I do that? Sorry if this is a silly question. Also it seems to output to the screen, I tried piping it but that didn't seem to work. I'm a novice at this. Maybe explaining exactly what it's doing too would help me out. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Okay I think I understand the loop. The NR is the # of input records awk has processed since the beginning of the programs execution. FNR is the current record number in the current file. Once it finds the close statement the i++ increments the value of i and the loop repeats. When i<3 it retains the first 3 characters close sensor * and if i==3 it grabs the 4th and 5th characters and replaces them for the i<3 matches. It performs this on the first file. THe next statment starts performing it on the second file (same in this case) and if it is the last statement it adds the close 12/31/2500

Comment: Okay this works for the first station, but the issue is there may be more than 3 entries, there could be hundreds. I just want to take the 3rd match and replace the two before it and keep moving on from there. I want to do this for each station in the station list, so if stalist = "WP00 WP01" I would like to do this for all the entries for WP00 and then move on through the file and do it for all of the entries for WP01 and so on. Does this make sense? How would I modify this portion of the code to do this?