# awk on two keywords within foreach loop

Tags: loops, replace, awk, pattern-matching

I have a text file that I would like to loop through on a particular keyword and find another keyword for that subgroup. Actually once it loops through the particular keyword I would like to find the last listed entry of the second keyword and change the date and time to "12/31/2500 23:59:59".

The text file looks like:

```
sta first keyword lat long depth
time date time
add
second keyword sensor type date time

sensor
add 
second keyword sensor type 10/31/2013 23:59:59
----------------------------------------------
sta first keyword lat long depth
time date time
add
second keyword sensor type date time

sensor
add 
second keyword sensor type date time
```

So I would like to loop through the first keyword and find the last entry of the second keyword in the text file and change the date time on the "second keyword sensor type date time" line to 12/31 2500 for the data and 23:59:59 for the time.

I would like to do this with awk, but haven't been able to find a good way. Can anyone help me out or steer me in the right direction? I am relatively new to awk and still learning and reading about the syntax structure.

The expected output from above would then be:

```
sta first keyword lat long depth
time date time
add
second keyword sensor type date time

sta first keyword lat long depth
time date time
add 
second keyword sensor type 12/31/2500 23:59:59
```

Note that there may be more than just the 2 blocks of texts shown above.

My idea of looping through would be either in awk somehow or with a foreach loop, so 
    foreach i (first keyword)
    awk #####

Something like that, or just with awk. The whole block of text is associated with each other, as there are different sta first keyword entries. These are station names that I would be calling. Make sense or still need more explanation?

To update this question further:
This is the what I have developed from help and on my own for the first part of my other question (there's a link in the comments):

```
     awk -F '[ : ]' 'NR==FNR && /time/ { A[++N]=$2" "$3":"$4":"$5-01 }; NR==FNR { next }; /time/ 
     {    M++ }; M && ((M%2) == 1) && /close/ {  NF=3 ; $0=$0" "A[M+1]   } 1'
     "$piername"_comprehensive20"$year"_bfile.txt "$piername"_comprehensive20"$year"_bfile.txt  
     >> "$piername"_20"$year"_bfile.txt
```

What this does is takes the time from the next station block definition and puts it in the close times for the previous station block (both close statements for the one station block) and subtracts one second.

To clarify, each station block contains 2 close statements, which is not as clear as I would've hope to be above. So the above entry would be one station block, and I added another one, which could either be a different station name, i.e, WP00 and then WP01. What I would like to do is with the very last station entry (containing 2 close statements), to make both of those close statements be 12/31/2500. I would like to maintain what I've done above with my awk statement for the rest of the station blocks for each station.

I hope this helps clarify what I mean :)

To update the question further, I think with the help of Hakon, here's the solution:

```
awk -F '[ : ]' '
NR==FNR {
    if (/time/)
        A[++N]=$2" "$3":"$4":"($5-01)
    else if (/close/) {
        B[FNR]=0
        n1=n2;
        n2=FNR;
    }
    else if (/^sta EP/) {
        match($0,/^sta EP([0-9]*)/,a)
        snr=a[1]
        if (snr != prev) {
            B[n1]=1
            B[n2]=1
        }
        prev=snr
    }
    next
}

FNR==1 {
    B[n1]=1; B[n2]=1
}
/time/ {
    M++
}
/close/ {
    if (B[FNR])
        $0=$1" ""sta"" ""12/31/2013 23:59:59"
    else if ((M%2) == 0 || (M%2) == 1) {
        NF=3
        $0=$0" "A[M+1]
    }
}
{print}' file file
```

I modified this slightly to try to do a few different things with where I inevitably want to go with the script. But all of the pieces are there.

Comment: Post the expected output for the given input as it's not clear what you want. It's particularly unclear what "to loop through the first keyword" means - how can you loop through a word? Make sure your posted sample input file contains actual sample input and not just an abstract description of the sample input.

Comment: I think he means to loop through the block that's delimited by the two keywords. But I'm not sure what he really means, since he just wants to change the last entry of the second keyword, so what does the first keyword have to do with it?

Comment: so say using those two entries I posted above that it would be

Comment: @user1332577 update your question, don't try to put it in a comment.

Comment: How is this question different than your previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20107224/awk-grep-replace-2nd-match-after-first-match-in-text-file-while-in-foreach-loop)?

Comment: I figured out how to do the first part of that question on my own with comments in the right direction from other users. But the second part still has me hung up and the comment on there only did it for the last entry of the text file and not for each specific sta keyword entry. I was hoping that if I was more specific about just this section I may be able to get further clarification.

Comment: In your example, what are these "keywords" you mention? Are they the words "lat" and "sensor" or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your previous post: [awk/grep replace 2nd match after first match in text file while in foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20107224/awk-grep-replace-2nd-match-after-first-match-in-text-file-while-in-foreach-loop) 
i figured out that you might want to change the last `close` before the next `station` keyword? 
Then you can try something like:

```
awk -f m.awk file file
```

where `file` is your input file and `m.awk` is:

```
FNR==NR {
    if (/^close/) {
        z[++k]=FNR
        if (k==3) {
            key=$4 FS $5
            b[z[1]]=key
            b[z[2]]=key
        }
        prev=FNR
    } else if (/^sta/) {
        a[prev]=1
        k=0
    }
    next
}
FNR==1 { a[prev]=1 }
{
    if (/^close/) {
        if (FNR in b)
          $0=$1FS$2FS$3FS b[FNR]
        if (a[FNR])
            $0=$1FS$2FS$3FS"12/31/2500 23:59:59"
    }
    print
}
```

For example, given the following input file:

```
sta WP00 34.07335 -106.91932 1.43

close sensor trillium_240_2 10/23/2013 20:10:17
bla

close sensor trillium_120 10/28/2013 20:20:45

close sensor trillium_80 10/28/2013 20:30:17

close sensor trillium_60 10/28/2013 20:40:29

close sensor trillium_40 10/28/2013 20:50:10

sta WP01 34.07335 -106.91932 1.43

close sensor trillium_240_2 10/23/2013 20:10:17
bla
bla

close sensor trillium_120 10/28/2013 20:20:45

close sensor trillium_120 10/28/2013 20:20:45

close sensor trillium_80 10/28/2013 20:30:17

close sensor trillium_40 10/28/2013 20:50:10
```

and running `awk -f m.awk file file` gives output:

```
sta WP00 34.07335 -106.91932 1.43

close sensor trillium_240_2 10/28/2013 20:30:17
bla

close sensor trillium_120 10/28/2013 20:30:17

close sensor trillium_80 10/28/2013 20:30:17

close sensor trillium_60 10/28/2013 20:40:29

close sensor trillium_40 12/31/2500 23:59:59

sta WP01 34.07335 -106.91932 1.43

close sensor trillium_240_2 10/28/2013 20:20:45
bla
bla

close sensor trillium_120 10/28/2013 20:20:45

close sensor trillium_120 10/28/2013 20:20:45

close sensor trillium_80 10/28/2013 20:30:17

close sensor trillium_40 12/31/2500 23:59:59
```

### Update

Based on discussion in the comments below, I give a new version:

```
NR==FNR {
    if (/time/)
        A[++N]=$2" "$3":"$4":"($5-1)
    else if (/close/) {
        B[FNR]=0
        n1=n2;
        n2=FNR;
    }
    else if (/^sta WP/) {
        match($0,/^sta WP([0-9]*)/,a)
        snr=a[1]
        if (snr != prev) {
            B[n1]=1
            B[n2]=1
        }
        prev=snr
    }
    next
}

FNR==1 {
    B[n1]=1; B[n2]=1
}
/time/ {
    M++
}
/close/ {
    if (B[FNR]) {
        $0=$1" "$2" "$3" 12/31/2500 23:59:59"
    }
    else if (M%2) {
        NF=3
        $0=$0" "A[M+1]
    }
}
{print}
```

Running this with input:

```
sta WP00 34.07335 -106.91932 1.43
time 10/23/2013 20:10:17
close sensor trillium_240_2 10/23/2013 20:10:17
add
close sensor trillium_120 10/23/2013 20:10:35
sta WP00 34.07335 -106.91932 1.43
time 10/28/2013 20:20:28
close sensor trillium_240_2 10/28/2013 20:20:28
close sensor trillium_120 10/28/2013 20:20:45
sta WP00 34.07335 -106.91932 1.43
time 10/28/2013 20:22:30
close sensor trillium_240_2 10/28/2013 20:24:28
close sensor trillium_120 10/28/2013 20:25:45
sta WP01 34.07335 -106.91932 1.43
time 10/23/2013 20:30:17
close sensor trillium_240_2 10/23/2013 20:10:17
add
close sensor trillium_120 10/23/2013 20:10:35
sta WP01 34.07335 -106.91932 1.43
time 10/28/2013 20:40:28
close sensor trillium_240_2 10/28/2013 20:20:28
close sensor trillium_120 10/28/2013 20:20:45
```

produces output:

```
sta WP00 34.07335 -106.91932 1.43
time 10/23/2013 20:10:17
close sensor trillium_240_2 10/28/2013 20:20:27
add
close sensor trillium_120 10/28/2013 20:20:27
sta WP00 34.07335 -106.91932 1.43
time 10/28/2013 20:20:28
close sensor trillium_240_2 10/28/2013 20:20:28
close sensor trillium_120 10/28/2013 20:20:45
sta WP00 34.07335 -106.91932 1.43
time 10/28/2013 20:22:30
close sensor trillium_240_2 12/31/2500 23:59:59
close sensor trillium_120 12/31/2500 23:59:59
sta WP01 34.07335 -106.91932 1.43
time 10/23/2013 20:30:17
close sensor trillium_240_2 10/23/2013 20:10:17
add
close sensor trillium_120 10/23/2013 20:10:35
sta WP01 34.07335 -106.91932 1.43
time 10/28/2013 20:40:28
close sensor trillium_240_2 12/31/2500 23:59:59
close sensor trillium_120 12/31/2500 23:59:59
```

Comment: Hakon, that's very close. But I only want the very last station keyword entry before the next differing station keyword one to be 12/31/2500. This above changes every other close statement to have an end time of 12/31/2500

Comment: if sta were a variable that I was looping through how would I call it in your previous statement? I.e., I'm trying to loop through WP00, WP01, WP02, etc to where it would recognize that it's the last one. That's where I'm hung up on this.

Comment: @user1332577 I think it changes the very last keyword in the station section, have you tried it? (I think it looks like it changes every other, due to the simple example I used)

Comment: @user1332577 I have updated my answer to show how you can incorporate the stuff from your previous question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20107224/awk-grep-replace-2nd-match-after-first-match-in-text-file-while-in-foreach-loop)

Comment: Thanks for keeping at it Hakon, but this is still changing every other entry. I am going to update my question to show you what I have so far that I've figured out and then maybe show you what I would like. You seem to be very good with awk, maybe this would help clarify what I mean

Comment: @user1332577 I have looked at your update, but it is not clear to me yet.. If you look at the output from my answer above: What do you mean by `changing every other entry` ? I cannot see any problems from the output..

Comment: @user1332577 Another question: Why do you use `'[ : ]'` as the field separator to the awk command?

Comment: Hakon I use [:] as the field separator for the time, so I can edit the time in the close statements. I mean it is changing every other close entry, but there are two close entries per station block. So it is leaving one unchanged and changing the last close to 12/31/2500 for every station block. I only want it to change both close statements for the very last station block...does this make more sense? So say my first station is WP00, I only want to change the two close statements for the very last station block to 12/31/2500 23:59:59. Then it would move to the next station WP01 and do the same

Comment: @user1332577 Yes it does make sense I think.. How many station blocks are there in the file? Do you mean a station block is separated by WP00 and WP01, or is a station block saparated by `close` keywords?

Comment: There could be up to n station blocks in a file, it really varies. I want to keep it open to accept as many as it can. Each station block has 2 close statements, the last close statement separates it from the next station block, which could either be the same station or a new station. What would delineate the end of station WP00 is when the last station close statement occurs and the first WP01 station block starts.

Comment: I edited the station blocks above to show a dash line that separates them and changed the text to make it more clear. Does this help?

Comment: @user1332577 I have updated my answer.. Am I getting closer now?

Comment: You are getting closer..this one does it for a small subset, say if you only had two. With the larger subset it still is doing every other station block...

Comment: Thanks! That seems to do the last one as 12/31/2500 but it doesn't maintain the other things I wanted that I had in my code above. Perhaps just doing the last one as 12/31/2500? I'm trying to fiddle with it to see if I can get just that.

Comment: @user1332577 What other things do you mean?

Comment: When I run it on my file it only changes every other station block, so for example the first station block is changed but the second one remains unchanged. So every other one is unchanged, instead of each station taking on the previous time value of station block after it.

Comment: I saw you were trying to incorporate the every other block like what I did in my code example..maybe it isn't executing that part? I'm still fiddling with things to see if I change it slightly it will work.

Comment: Maybe if I gave you my full text file so you could see?

Comment: I updated my question with the edits that change your scripted version to do what I intended. I appreciate all of your help that you've given me and the persistence you've had! The last bit I want to do is to actually have it say "close sta staname 12/31/2013 23:59:59" where staname would be WP[0-9]*, do you think that would be difficult to do?

Comment: @user1332577 You are welcome. It has been an interesting problem. For your updated solution: Why do you use `EP` and not `WP`?

Comment: Oh sorry, EP was the text file I was working on. I'm doing this for a variety of text files. So some stations have EP, other WP, SP, and NP. So I will probably just do *P[0-9]*. Do you know how I would get it to insert the sta name it's looping through into the last close statements?

Comment: Haegland, do you know how I would actually insert the station name (either EP* or WP*) into the last close statements? Instead of saying close sensor 12/31/2013 23:59:59.

Comment: @user1332577 Sorry I did not see your comment from Dec 12.. I will have a look at it..

Comment: @user1332577 Do you have an email address? Then I email you a suggestion for your last question.. I would rather not like to update the answer here, since that would notify everybody else, and I think that is not appropriate, since this problem is now too involved that anybody other than me and you can possibly understand it..

Comment: @user1332577 Or you can send me an email at `hakon.hagland@uni.no` and I reply to that..